# Wordpress single post URL

Tags: wordpress, url, blogs

I'm building a Wordpress for a client and everything is going fine but I have changed the permalinks to displaying post title but now at the end of the URL it is adding a random string fo characters at the end

**#.UJPe_2moqsg**

This is only happening on the single posts rather than the rest of the site.

Has anyone seen this before.

Other details, latest version of Wordpress, using the Starkers theme as a base. I have tried another theme and it doesn't seem to be happening.

Should I be looking anywhere in specific that could be making this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's AddThis adding these characters onto your URL - it's nothing to do with WordPress itself.
If you remove this line from the AddThis code, the characters should go away:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
```

AddThis adds those characters on so that it can track shares by people sharing by copying and pasting your URL. If you just want to track standard shares via the AddThis buttons, you don't need this data tracking on and your standard URLs won't be interfered with.